# Microcontroller Process Interference Protection

Tags: operating-system, microcontroller

What limitations does an operating system running on a microcontroller typically
face with regard to protecting processes from undesirable interference
of other processes?

Comment: Which uController?  Does yours have a hardware MMU?

Comment: it is very hardware specific, if the chip/processor does not have protection designed in the basically you have no protection.  if it does have protection then your protection is limited by what the chip has provided and the operating system needs to work around/with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very general answer to a rather wide question.
The only limitation there would be the absence/presence of [MMU (Memory Management Unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). If there is one on the microcontroller the protection of porcesse's address space is just correctly handling the attepts to access "someone's" address sapce (most often - in a form of interrupt handling).

If there is no MMU on the processor/controller - there things become interesting, which in the end falls into a case where a software developer should excercise certain discipline, while accessing memory locations.  OS can't help a lot in this case.